# Массовое добавление постов

Tags: php, mysql

Существует таблица с уже заполненной информацией, у каждой записи есть свой id и чекбокс на удаление.

[image]

Выбрав чекбоксы мы нажимаем на кнопочку "Опубликовать выбранные". В результате ссылка на файл `http://site.ru/step2.php?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4` (где 1, 2, 3, 4 - посты которые надо добавить). Этот файл называется step1.php. step2.php - это добавление выбранных записей. С вот этой ссылкой `http://site.ru/step2.php?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4`.

Нужно, когда новость с i`d=4` добавилась - автоматически стиралось `&id=4` и мы переходили на редактирование новости уже с `id=3`.

Как это стирание реализовать? Скажите, хотя бы в какую сторону гуглить. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

А теперь по порядку.

В вопросе много подпунктов и сам вопрос задан как-то неправильно, столько непонятного.

1

> Существует таблица с уже заполненной информацией, у каждой записи есть свой id и чекбокс на удаление.

Окей существует!

2

> Выбрав чекбоксы мы нажимаем на
> кнопочку "Опубликовать выбранные".

Посылаем скрипту массив ID записей и меняем статусы у записей, тут должно быть просто.

3

> http://site.ru/step2.php?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4

И что это реально работает? т.е. перечислить подряд в GET одну и туже переменную с разными значениями и мы получаем разные значения при обращении к $_GET['id']?? Круто, или я чего-то не знаю?

4

> Нужно, когда новость с id=4 добавилась
> - автоматически стиралось &id=4 и мы переходили на редактирование новости
> уже с id=3.

Что прости добавилось? Куда добавилось? В вопросе про добавление новостей нет ничего, есть только про изменение статуса новости. Или я опять не вижу скрытый смысл вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Сложно как то, делаем так - выбрали чекбоксы - постом отправили, на сервере приняли и вцикле сделали записям апдейт

Answer (score 1):

Не используй для этого GET. 
Попробуй просто это всё передать через POST. Причем еще скрытым полем `<input>` добавь с какого номера начинаются посты и каким заканчиваются(на рисунке 152-166). Еще у чекбоксов добавь `value - 1`. и добавь туда `id='его номер в таблице'`. К примеру получится:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check' id='154' value=1>
```

Потом просто сделай цикл:

```
   for ($i=152; $i<=166; $i++)
    {
      if ($_POST['check'] == 1)
      {
      дальше уже делаем что нужно.
      }
    }
```

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил.

Answer (score 1):

Гуглите в сторону [массивов в php](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php). Отправляйте массив с выбранными id. (get или post без разницы, но лучше post)

Чекбоксы будут выглядеть вот так:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="цифра" />
```

Строка в get-запросе будет выглядеть вот так:

```
http://site.ru/step2.php?id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3
```

В переменной $_GET['id'] или ($_POST['id']) будет **[массив](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2)**